# How can I get less or cat to use color in the output from .cat of my .bashrc, similar to vi 'ing it?

Tags: command-line, colors, cat, less

When I vi my .bashrc file it is colorized, i.e.

[image]

but when I `cat` or `less` the file I get all white, i.e.

[image]

How can I get `cat` (and `less`) to have color?

cat does have color for my ruby `.rb` files but not for these bash dot files the way that vi does for bash dot files.

less doesn't have color for ruby `.rb` files at all.

Gnome terminal is `3.6.1`
Ubuntu is `13.04`
Bash is `v4.2.45(1)`

Comment: I had tried this previously with unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100841/how-can-i-colorize-cat-output-including-unknown-filetypes-in-bw?rq=1 but that isn't working now.  Not sure why.

Comment: Please always include the actual error you get, "it fails" with no explanation is not very useful. In this case, the error explains the problem precisely and would have saved all of us some time.

Comment: Sure.  I thought "
When I vi my .bashrc file it is colorized,
but when I cat or less the file I get all white,How can I get cat (and less) to have color?" was all I needed.

Comment: Yes, but that is already answered nicely in the linked question. Since you linked to it, I am assuming you tried that and got the error in my answer. That's what I mean, in the future please include the errors you get.

Comment: I did not get that error.  Text is just white(uncolored).

Comment: There is a nice program `pygmentize` that does what you initially wanted: `pygmentize -g filename` (see a related question at [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14799752/1800052)).

Comment: bat is a cat-clone. Please see:
https://github.com/sharkdp/bat

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Trying to run `source-highlight` as suggested in the linked question produces this error:

```
$ source-highlight -o STDOUT -i .bashrc --out-format=esc
source-highlight: could not find a language definition for input file .bashrc
```

That's because `.bashrc` is not recognized automatically by `source-highlight`,  a quick look through its manual shows that it has the `-s` flag to set a language, so what you need is:

```
source-highlight -s bash -o STDOUT -i .bashrc --out-format=esc | less -R
```

Comment: +1 great.  thanks.  how does vi manage to do this without me listing the file this way?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant vi has it's own syntax definition rules and can detect bash syntax better apparently. They are completely separate programs, no reason to expect them to work in the same way.